# vba excel stays open when moving an excel sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I have this code.  I am basically generating a list on one sheet and renaming it to RSSR List.  I then take that sheet and move it to an existing sheet.  What happens is the last lines of code don't save the workbook that I do all the formatting on and excel doesn't close.  The workbook that I moved the sheet to saves and that instance of excel is closed.  When I end task on excel and rerun the code it says that the instance no longer exists something like the server or machine no longer exists.  I can't get the excel sheet that I moving over to save and get the instance of excel closed.  If it kill excel it errors out the next time I run the procedure.  I want excel to close during this procedure.  Here is my code:

```
Public Function BrooksFormatBrooks()
Dim xlApp As Excel.Application
Dim xlApp2 As Excel.Application
Dim wb As Excel.Workbook
Dim ws As Excel.Worksheet
Dim wb2 As Excel.Workbook
Dim ws2 As Excel.Worksheet
Dim MyFileName As String
Dim afile As String
Dim bfile As String

afile = "S:\Brooks\Tyco-Brooks Receiving Tracking MASTER V 1.4 2017-05-06.xlsx"
bfile = "S:\_Reports\Brooks\Tyco-Brooks Receiving Tracking MASTER - "

MyFileName = bfile & Format(Date, "mm-dd-yyyy") & ".xls"
MyFileName2 = afile

On Error Resume Next
Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
On Error GoTo 0

Set wb2 = xlApp2.Workbooks.Open(MyFileName2)
Set ws2 = wb2.Sheets(1)
ws2.Activate

xlApp.DisplayAlerts = False
wb2.Sheets("RSSR_List").Delete
xlApp.DisplayAlerts = True

wb2.CheckCompatibility = False
wb2.Save
wb2.CheckCompatibility = True
wb2.Close SaveChanges:=False

xlApp.Quit

Set xlApp = Nothing
Set wb2 = Nothing
Set ws2 = Nothing

On Error Resume Next
Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
On Error GoTo 0

Set wb = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(MyFileName)
Set ws = wb.Sheets(1)
ws.Activate

wb.Sheets(1).Name = "RSSR_List"

Set ws = wb.Sheets(1)
ws.Activate

wb.ActiveSheet.ListObjects.Add(xlSrcRange, Range("$A$1:$F$312"), , xlYes).Name = _
     "RSSR"

ws.Range("A1:F312").Select

ws.Cells.Rows("2:2").Select
xlApp.ActiveWindow.FreezePanes = False
xlApp.ActiveWindow.FreezePanes = True

ws.Columns("A:Z").HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
ws.Rows("1:1").Font.Bold = True
ws.Rows("1:1").Font.ColorIndex = 1
ws.Rows("1:1").Interior.ColorIndex = 15
ws.Cells.Font.Name = "Calbri"
ws.Cells.Font.Size = 8
ws.Cells.EntireColumn.AutoFit
ws.Cells.EntireRow.AutoFit

xlApp.Cells.Borders.LineStyle = xlContinuous
xlApp.Cells.Borders.Weight = xlThin
xlApp.Cells.Borders.ColorIndex = 0

ws.Cells.Rows("1:1").Select

wb.CheckCompatibility = False
wb.Save
wb.CheckCompatibility = True
wb.Close SaveChanges:=False

Set wb2 = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(MyFileName2)

MsgBox "Before Move"
ws.Move Before:=Workbooks("Tyco-Brooks Receiving Tracking MASTER V 1.4 2017-05-06.xlsx").Sheets(1)
MsgBox "AFter Move"

wb2.CheckCompatibility = False
wb2.Save
wb2.CheckCompatibility = True
wb2.Close SaveChanges:=True

Set wb = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(MyFileName)

wb.CheckCompatibility = False
wb.Save
wb.CheckCompatibility = True
wb.Close SaveChanges:=True

xlApp.Quit

Set xlApp = Nothing
Set wb = Nothing
Set ws = Nothing
Set wb2 = Nothing
Set ws2 = Nothing


End Function
```

Comment: `Dim xlApp2 As Excel.Application` then `Set wb2 = xlApp2.Workbooks.Open(MyFileName2)` you are using a non-initialized variable here (`xlApp2`), how did that pass? Did you post your exact code? Besides why do you want two `Excel.Application` objects?

Comment: Is this Excel VBA code?  If so, why do you need **any** extra Excel Application objects?  (Or is this MSAccess or MSWord [etc] code that is just using Excel?)

Comment: (a) You have a few unqualified references - `Range("$A$1:$F$312")` should be `ws.Range("$A$1:$F$312")` rather than defaulting to `Application.ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$F$312")`, and `Before:=Workbooks("Tyco-Brooks Receiving Tracking MASTER V 1.4 2017-05-06.xlsx").Sheets(1)` should be `Before:=xlApp.Workbooks("Tyco-Brooks Receiving Tracking MASTER V 1.4 2017-05-06.xlsx").Sheets(1)` (b) It is probably dangerous to do a move of a worksheet after the workbook that sheet is in has been closed.

Comment: @YowE3K what about `Set wb2 = xlApp2...` with `xlApp2` non-initialized? Did I miss something?

Comment: @A.S.H - no, that is definitely bad (especially when the OP then uses `xlApp.DisplayAlerts` prior to deleting the sheet of the workbook that exists in `xlApp2`), but you had already mentioned that so I didn't bother repeating it.  I suspect there has been a bit of playing with code, and the version posted wasn't the version used to produce the symptoms described in the question.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes these sorts of issues can be solved by putting a `DoEvents` call after the offending operation. So in this case you'd have something like:

```
MsgBox "Before Move"
ws.Move Before:=Workbooks("Tyco-Brooks Receiving Tracking MASTER V 1.4 2017-05-06.xlsx").Sheets(1)
DoEvents
MsgBox "AFter Move"
```

This tends to be necessary for Excel 2016.

Comment: i did the following

Comment: ws.move Before:=xlApp.Workbooks(..... and added doevents below that and that closed out excel just fine now  Thank you thank you thank you  I have been beating my head for hours now.

Answer (score 0):

```
ws.Move Before:=xlApp.Workbooks("Tyco-Brooks Receiving Tracking Master V 1.4...)Sheets(1)
DoEvents
```

This worked.

Comment: How did your code get past the use of the uninitialised `xlApp2`?  (And the `DoEvents` in your answer isn't required.  Or, at least, it **shouldn't** be required.)

Comment: `DoEvents` shouldn't be required in Excel 2016, but sadly it sometimes is. You have to sprinkle them around like candy to get things to work the way they did in Excel 2013.